# How to delete safari cookies in programatically

Tags: ios, cookies, session-cookies, flickr

I have worked on Flickr. In that i have  want  to clear the safari cookies, when calling the flick login screen in safari.how to clear the cookies.please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, apps run in a sandbox and can't access other apps directly.

If you mean with Safari a `UIWebView` then you can delete them via the [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001703-387826):

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage =  [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie  *cookie in [cookieStorage cookies]) {
   [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with that, but is a pretty raw clean

```
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
```